# Undefined Method 'Match' for Nil Class with Oracle Enhanced Adapter Connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, oracle11g

I am using the [activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced#activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter) to connect to an Oracle 11g Database so that I may more easily reference the data living in Oracle in my Rails 4 Application. I have been following the instructions in the GitHub repo so far and it appears as if I am in fact able to connect to the database that I want to, but whenever I go to query any data in the Oracle Database I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass

from /Users/47900/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:322:in `new_connection'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:389:in `initialize'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:26:in `new'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:26:in `initialize'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/connection.rb:9:in `new'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/connection.rb:9:in `create'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:156:in `oracle_enhanced_connection'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /Users/47900/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
```

I have tried googling the issue (and checking the docs / issues), but haven't found anything useful. I am also able to access this database through sqlplus, so my Oracle Instant Client is in fact working. Here is my database.yml and model that I have configured and am using to try to query the Oracle DB:

```
#database.yml (obviously data is faked)

  development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  host: //127.0.0.1:1527/DATABASE_NAME
  username: ENV['USERNAME']
  password: ENV['PASSWORD']

#oracle.rb

  class Oracle < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "SCHEMA.TABLE"
    self.primary_key = "obj_id"
  end

#The queries I have tried through Rails Console

  >> Oracle
  >> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE obj_id > 1000000;")
```

I'll keep updating with more information as I acquire it, thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the database.yml config file you are missing "database". Use database.yml file described in https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced#database-connection

Checkout this code https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/blob/master/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb line: 302 and 322

database.yml

```
    development:
      adapter: oracle_enhanced
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 1527
      database: <DATABASE_NAME>
      username: ENV['USERNAME']
      password: ENV['PASSWORD']
```